# Interprocess communication between python file (started as batch command in jenkins) and jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins. I need to run a python script as batch command in Jenkins pipeline.

There are 4 places in python script where it takes input from user(raw_input command) when I executed from command line.

Same script I want to execute from Jenkins pipeline, so where ever script takes input from user, I want to send mail to user, stop python script execution and wait for user input, once user provides input, proceed for further execution.

So basically I'm looking for inter-process communication between python script which is run as batch file and Jenkins.